# Firefox can only be started by sudo

Tags: 16.04, permissions, firefox

Firefox on an Ubuntu 16.04 server can only be launched by `sudo` at the server machine. Firefox cannot be started using a regular account even by entering the command on the same keyboard attached to the server machine.

The error message at the command line is :

```
Access is denied while trying to open file in your profile directory.
```

Access right of my .profile is :

```
-rw-r--r--
```

The result of `ls -lsa ~/.mozilla`

```
drwx------   (for all 4 directories : . .. extensions firefox)
```

All directories owners and groups are under my username.

The result of `sudo ls -lsa ~/.cache/mozilla`

```
drwx------   (for all 3 directories : . .. firefox)
```

Directories owners and groups are under my username except .. (parent)
.. is owned by root and its group name is also root.

Need to use sudo above because the above command cannot be executed without sudo.

Have tried the following command but the problem persists.

```
# fix the permissions

sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache/mozilla
```

Have also tried reinstalling firefox with x-windows and related graphical files but doesn't help.

Comment: *Never* run Firefox or any other browser as root. Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should adjust your user rights in general like Yaron said.

`sudo chown [user]:[usergroup] -R ~/`

On top of that just a information don't use `sudo "gui-programm"` always use `gksudo` so such things don't happen again.

Comment: I think I missed out the access right of the root directory part. Many thanks to both you and Yaron ... :)   Now firefox comes up perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox also uses `~/.mozilla` folder

You should make sure that the permission of the `~/.mozilla` folder is correct, using:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.mozilla
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have just tried it but the problem seems to be still here. Will try again later tonight.

Comment: @Stanley please [edit] your question, and add the result of `ls -lsa ~/.mozilla` and `ls -lsa ~/.cache/mozilla`